# Simple Z-Index not working

Tags: html, css, z-index

I am trying to place my header `<h1>` over a div class named `light` which contains a background image named `light.png`. I have stacked them using `Z-index` and added `position:relative`, but still `<h1>` is not placed over `<div class=light>`.

What am I doing wrong? Here is my **html code**:

```
<body>
    <div class="light"></div>
    <h1>sdfdsf</h1>
</body>
```

**css code:**

```css
body {
    background-image: url(images/bg.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    z-index:1;
}
.light {
    background-image: url(images/light.png);
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    z-index:2;
    width:763px;
    height:566px;
    position:relative;
}
h1 {
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size: 48px;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    position:relative;
    z-index:5;
}
```

Comment: Can I ask why you dont want to put the h1 inside the div. If the image is used for a background image then the h1 will still display over the top of the image.

Comment: so you have really stacked them using z-index ?

Comment: Encapsulate them in a outer div, position relative the outer div and position absolute the two inner elements, done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is to place your `<h1>` tag inside the `<div>` tag.

```
<div class="light">
    <h1>sdfdsf</h1>
</div>
```

**Live example: [Tinkerbin](http://tinkerbin.com/5Ixbodio)**
*I modified your background color to show the example*.

You don't need to use `z-index` for this.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an exmaple of what I said in my comment:

**html code:**

```
<body>
  <div class='outer'>
      <div class="light"></div>
      <h1>sdfdsf</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

**css code:**

```
body {
   background-image: url(images/bg.jpg);
   background-repeat: repeat;
}

.outer{
   position:relative;
}
.light {
   background-image: url(images/light.png);
   margin-left:auto;
   margin-right:auto;
   width:763px;
   height:566px;
   position:absolute;
}
h1 {
   font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
   font-size: 48px;
   color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
   position:absolute;
   z-index:99999999999;
   top:0;
   left:0;
}
```

You can use all posiiton relatives but it is not fully browser compliant due to `CSS` bugs so I prefer to do this way since this will look ok on older browsers too, not just the new ones.

Answer (score 2):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dipaks2011/pW23Q/1/)

There is no need to assign `z-index` to the body

HTML -

```
<div class="light"></div>
<h1>hi</h1>​
```

CSS -

```
.light {
    background-image: url(http://www.ostpl.com/Gallery/web-hosting.jpg);
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    z-index:1;
    width:763px;
    height:566px;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    position: relative;
}
h1 {
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size: 48px;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
    position:absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index:2;
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

put `<h1>` tag inside the `div light`

```
 <body>
    <div class="light">
      <h1>sdfdsf</h1>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

use absolute instead

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    body {
        background-color: black;
        background-repeat: repeat;
        z-index:1;
    }
    .light {
        background-color: yellow;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        z-index:2;
        width:763px;
        height:566px;
        position:absolute;
    }
    h1 {
        font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
        font-size: 48px;
        color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
        position:absolute;
        z-index:5;
    }
</style>
```

- absolute : The element is positioned relative to its first positioned
  (not static) ancestor element
- relative : The element is positioned
  relative to its normal position, so "left:20" adds 20 pixels to the
  element's LEFT position

Answer (score 1):

***See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uA4m5/2/)***

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="light"></div>
  <h1>sdfdsf</h1>
</body>​
```

CSS:

```
.light {
    position:relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #ccc;
    z-index: 1;
}

h1 {
    position:relative;
    z-index: 2;
    top: -10px;
}​
```

Bigger z-index - Higher element.